# How to include implicit wait in seleniumbase?

Tags: python, seleniumbase

how could i include implicitly_wait in selenium base?

```
from seleniumbase import SB
```

I'm accessing the google account and I only managed with selenium base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SeleniumBase waits are already included with default timeout values. Without the waits, a script may look like this:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB() as sb:  # By default, browser="chrome" if not set.
    sb.open("https://seleniumbase.io/realworld/login")
    sb.type("#username", "demo_user")
    sb.type("#password", "secret_pass")
    sb.enter_mfa_code("#totpcode", "GAXG2MTEOR3DMMDG")  # 6-digit
    sb.assert_text("Welcome!", "h1")
    sb.highlight("img#image1")  # A fancier assert_element() call
    sb.click('a:contains("This Page")')  # Use :contains() on any tag
    sb.click_link("Sign out")  # Link must be "a" tag. Not "button".
    sb.assert_element('a:contains("Sign in")')
    sb.assert_exact_text("You have been signed out!", "#top_message")
```

But with the waits, a script might look like this: (With `timeout=TIMEOUT` added)

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB() as sb:
    sb.open("https://seleniumbase.io/realworld/login")
    sb.type("#username", "demo_user", timeout=7)
    sb.type("#password", "secret_pass", timeout=8)
    sb.enter_mfa_code("#totpcode", "GAXG2MTEOR3DMMDG")
    sb.assert_text("Welcome!", "h1", timeout=9)
    sb.highlight("img#image1")
    sb.click('a:contains("This Page")', timeout=6)
    sb.click_link("Sign out", timeout=5)
    sb.assert_element('a:contains("Sign in")', timeout=4)
    sb.assert_exact_text("You have been signed out!", "#top_message", timeout=3)
```

Most methods have a `timeout` arg that can be included to change the default waiting time, as seen above.

Here's anther example that uses the SB Context Manager:

```py
with SB(test=True, rtf=True, demo=True) as sb:
    sb.open("seleniumbase.github.io/demo_page")
    sb.type("#myTextInput", "This is Automated")
    sb.assert_text("This is Automated", "#myTextInput")
    sb.assert_text("This Text is Green", "#pText")
    sb.click('button:contains("Click Me")')
    sb.assert_text("This Text is Purple", "#pText")
    sb.click("#checkBox1")
    sb.assert_element_not_visible("div#drop2 img#logo")
    sb.drag_and_drop("img#logo", "div#drop2")
    sb.assert_element("div#drop2 img#logo")
```